# Rollup plugin scss not executing

Tags: javascript, sass, rollupjs

I try to learn rollup to bundle for a small js/scss project. I want rollup to bundle and minify my js and scss files.
I wrote a configuration file for rollup. When I execute rollup, it correctly handle js file, but I don't have an output for the sass.
Can you help me to correct my mistake ?

Rollup config file

```
import scss from 'rollup-plugin-scss'

export default {
    input: 'src/js/main.js',
    output: [
        {
            file: "dist/main.js",
            format: 'cjs'
        },
    ],
    plugins: [
        scss({
            name: "dist/main.css",
            include: "src/sass/main.scss",
            outputStyle: "compressed",
            verbose: true, 
        }),
    ],
};
```

Console output

```
$ rollup --config rollup.config.js

src/js/main.js → dist/main.js...
created dist/main.js in 47ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a small typo mistake **name** should be **fileName**

https://github.com/thgh/rollup-plugin-scss#usage

```
export default {
    input: 'input.js',
    output: { file: 'output.js', format: 'esm' },
    plugins: [
        scss({ fileName: 'bundle.css' }) // will output compiled styles to "bundle.css"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).